# CSV error message not shown

Tags: php, csv

I am able to upload and overwrite the data from my CSV file.
But when I upload the wrong file type (example upload PPT file), the **error** message "Invalid File. Please check that the file is uploaded in .CSV format!" is **not shown**. But the good thing is my localhost database did not update too (since it's not the right file)
**How should I edit the code such that the error will be shown/prompted?**

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_POST["Upload"])) {
include "dbFunctions.php";
mysql_select_db($DB) or die(mysql_error());
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");


    $count = 0;
    while (($excelData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $count++;

        if ($count > 1) {
            $sql = "INSERT into abc (id, password, name, dob, contact_number, email, gender, module, school) values ('" . $excelData[0] . "',SHA1('" . $excelData[1] . "'),'" . $excelData[2] . "','" . $excelData[3] . "','" . $excelData[4] . "','" . $excelData[5] . "','" . $excelData[6] . "','" . $excelData[7] . "','" . $excelData[8] . "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password=SHA1('" . $excelData[1] . "'), name='$excelData[2]', dob='$excelData[3]', contact_number='$excelData[4]', email='$excelData[5]', gender='$excelData[6]', module='$excelData[7]', school='$excelData[8]'";
            mysql_query($sql);

            $msg = 'CSV File has been successfully imported';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Invalid File. Please check that the file is uploaded in .CSV format!';
             }
         }
     }
 }
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>**** System</title>
         <link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     </head>
     <body>
     <?php
    include "navigationBar.php";
    ?>

    <h2>Load Details</h2>
    <?php
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    ?>
    <br>
    <?php
    echo $msg
    ?>

</body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to show an error in a loop that reads data from file.

Try using `do {...} while(...)` loop to catch an error:

```
$count = 0;
do {
   $excelData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",");

   if ($excelData === FALSE && $count == 0) {
      //stop importing if first returned data is FALSE
      break;
   }
   elseif ($excelData !== FALSE) {
      $count++;
      $sql = "INSERT into abc (id, password, name, dob, contact_number, email, gender, module, school) values ('" . $excelData[0] . "',SHA1('" . $excelData[1] . "'),'" . $excelData[2] . "','" . $excelData[3] . "','" . $excelData[4] . "','" . $excelData[5] . "','" . $excelData[6] . "','" . $excelData[7] . "','" . $excelData[8] . "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password=SHA1('" . $excelData[1] . "'), name='$excelData[2]', dob='$excelData[3]', contact_number='$excelData[4]', email='$excelData[5]', gender='$excelData[6]', module='$excelData[7]', school='$excelData[8]'";
      mysql_query($sql);         
   } 
} while ($excelData !== FALSE);

// display message depending on number of rows imported
if ($count > 0) {
   $msg = 'CSV File has been successfully imported';
}
else {
   $msg = 'Invalid File. Please check that the file is uploaded in .CSV format!';
}
echo $msg;
```

**You could** (or possibly even should) check file's extension before it's uploaded. Of course the extension *does not* mean the data inside a file is properly formatted, but it *could be a hint*, that if you don't have the proper extenstion, the data could be *not-csv-like*.

To check file extension simpy use:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && strcasecmp('csv', pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) === 0) {
   // file extension is CSV 
} else {
   // file extension is NOT CSV
}
```

Comment: Try import jpg use fgetcsv. It return array

Comment: Also you must check mysql_query result:)

Comment: Sure you need to check it, but it's kind of outside the scope of the question. You could improve many things in this code ;)

Comment: @isg try add 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
into begin your file. And tell us what does it display.

Comment: @isg try add check if (count($excelData) < 8) {continue;} before $count++; construction; I hope it must help;

Comment: @stepozer 
Hey guys, thank you so much! It works well right now! :D